# The way to check that class has operator() with specific template

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I'm trying to use SFINAE technique to check - does class/struct have `operator()` with specific template declaration, for example (little bit simplified):

```cpp
struct Simplified
{
  //  1st operator - I need to detect its presence
  template<typename T, int I>
  void operator()(T& val1, double val2)
  {
    std::cout << std::to_string(val1 + val2) << std::to_string(I) << std::endl;
  }
    
  //  2nd operator
  void operator()(double& val1, double val2)
  {
    std::cout << std::to_string(val1 + val2) << std::endl;
  }
};
```

And I've got stuck with checking of `operator()` templated signature. Here's my helper class:

```cpp
template<typename Fn, int I, typename T>
class TemplatedOperatorCheck
{
  struct Exists { };
  struct NotExists { };

  template<typename U, void(U::*)(T&, double)> struct SFINAESimple {};
  template<typename U> static Exists Test(SFINAESimple<U, &(U::operator())>*);
  // The problem is probably there                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  template<typename U> static NotExists Test(...);
public:
  static constexpr bool kExists = std::is_same<decltype(Test<Fn>(nullptr)), Exists>::value;
};
```

But this class could only detect presence of the non-templated `operator()`.

```cpp
// true if 2nd operator declared in Simplified class, false otherwise.
auto DoubleOpValid = TemplatedOperatorCheck<Simplified, 0, double>::kExists;

// always false
auto IntOpValid = TemplatedOperatorCheck<Simplified, 0, int>::kExists;
```

What am I doing wrong? Cannot find anything related in Google or at stackoverflow...

Thanks in advance! Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: wouldn't [`std::is_invocable_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) do this for you?

Comment: I'm a bit confused... Do you want the test to detect only the first operator, only the second operator, or both?

Comment: @IgorG , actually I need to detect presence of only 1st operator. The second one is just for clarification on what should NOT be detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... not sure to understand what you exactly want but... I propose the following class

```
template<typename Fn, int I, typename T>
class TemplatedOperatorCheck
 {
   template<typename U, void(U::*)(T&, double)>
   struct SFINAESimple
    { };

   template<typename U>
   static std::true_type Test(SFINAESimple<U, &U::operator()>*, int);

   template<typename U>
   static std::true_type Test(SFINAESimple<U, &U::template operator()<T, I>>*, long);

   template<typename U>
   static std::false_type Test(...);

   public:
      static constexpr bool kExists = decltype(Test<Fn>(nullptr, 0))::value;
 };
```

Some observations, without particular order...

1. you can use `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`, instead of `Exist` and `NotExist`; so the `kExists` initialization is simplified and doesn't needs `std::is_same` anymore.
2. the correct syntax for the second template parameter, calling `SFINAESimple`, is without parentheses. I mean: `&U::operator()`, not `&(U::operator())`
3. your `Test()` function, passing the template parameter `&U::operator()` to `SFINAESimple`, works for non-template functions; if you want that works also for template functions, you have to generate the required function from the set of the possible functions, so I've added another `Test()` function that pass the `&U::template operator()<T, I>` parameter
4. Given that a class can have both template and non-template functions, the compiler select both `Test()` function returning `std::true` and give an error because it don't know which one prefer; to permit the compiler to prefer one version or another, I've added another argument (`int` in one, `long` in the other), so calling `Test<Fn>(nullptr, 0)`, the compiler prefer the `int` version (because `0`, the second argument, is a `int`), avoiding the ambiguity and avoiding the error.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>

struct Simplified
{
  //  1st operator - I need to detect its presence
  template<typename T, int I>
  void operator()(T & val1, double val2)
  {
    std::cout << std::to_string(val1 + val2) << std::to_string(I) << std::endl;
  }
    
  //  2nd operator
  void operator()(double & val1, double val2)
  {
    std::cout << std::to_string(val1 + val2) << std::endl;
  }
};

template<typename Fn, int I, typename T>
class TemplatedOperatorCheck
 {
   template<typename U, void(U::*)(T&, double)>
   struct SFINAESimple
    { };

   template<typename U>
   static std::true_type Test(SFINAESimple<U, &U::operator()>*, int);

   template<typename U>
   static std::true_type Test(SFINAESimple<U, &U::template operator()<T, I>>*, long);

   template<typename U>
   static std::false_type Test(...);

   public:
      static constexpr bool kExists = decltype(Test<Fn>(nullptr, 0))::value;
 };

int main()
 {
   auto DoubleOpValid = TemplatedOperatorCheck<Simplified, 0, double>::kExists;

   auto IntOpValid = TemplatedOperatorCheck<Simplified, 0, int>::kExists;

   std::cout << DoubleOpValid << ' ' << IntOpValid << '\n';
 }
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt and detailed reply. Unfortunately I'm not able to compile your code (at least at MSVC 2019 neither with c++14 nor with c++17 compilers) - it claims `error C2977: 'TemplatedOperatorCheck<Fn,I,T>::SFINAESimple': too many template arguments` and other errors - all on line containing `&U::template operator()<T, I>` . Even if I put just `TemplatedOperatorCheck` class in main.cpp and don't refer tp it.

Comment: @Ukridge - Uhmmm... maybe there are little differences in the `Simplified` struct you're using and the one you've transcripted in the example... anyway... added a full compiling example that compile with both clang++ and g++.

Comment: I've tried your full example, and got the same result on MSVC. And yes, your example, being compiled witah g++, works like a charm. It seems that there's some bug in cl (Microsoft compiler), and it's really confusing. I'm going to send bug report to Microsoft.
Thanks again for your help!